# Resharper File Template - Extract part of the current file name

Tags: resharper

I'm trying to create a "handler" file template so that when I enter a name of "GetBlogRequestHandler" the following will be generated:

```
public class GetBlogRequestHandler : IHandle<GetBlogRequest, GetBlogResponse> {

}
```

The problem is that given then following template

```
public class %VARIABLE%RequestHandler : IHandle<%VARIABLE%Request, %VARIABLE%Response> {

}
```

I want to be able to set the macro for `%VARIABLE%` to be "Current file name without extension", but without the `RequestHandler` part.

Is this possible, or are there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it's not possible to delete a part of macro variable, but you can create custom macro with desired functionality. Check this link for more information:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/10/templates-galore-extending-functionality-with-macros/